# Android processing display

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a function that creates a socket connection and then waits for a response. During this time I do not want the user to be able to click any buttons, else they can crash the application.

as such at the start of the function I do the following:

```
 public void Checkout()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new     AlertDialog.Builder(NuPos_testActivity.this);
        builder2.setMessage("Processing");
         AlertDialog alert2 = builder2.create();
         alert2.show();
```

This greys out the screen and displays processing till the response comes back from the server. My problem is while this is the first thing at the top of the function it only runs after everything else. I don't understand why?

To be more clear about my problem: I run an alert box before code, but it only shows after the code has finished running. how do I fix this?

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Showing an `AlertDialog` doesn't halt the code. It just prevents user interaction. If you want to delay further code execution until you are ready, look at something like `ASyncTask` which has an `onPostExecute()` method to notify you when the task is complete.

Comment: I want the code to execute. I just dont want the user to be able to click stuff while the Socket is waiting for a response. But as I said, Its running the socket connection and getting the response before greying out the screen and showing processing..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code sample above, and the code for your `Socket`, are running in the same `Thread` (which is the `UIThread`). If this is the case, Android will usually perform the 'processing' code first, and delay the painting until afterwards (as the painting has a lower priority).

You need to move the Socket code into a separate `Thread`, so that it can run independently from the `UIThread`, which should allow Android the time to display the `AlertDialog` earlier.